# Why my multiple-command vim command-mode abbreviation will be executed automatically when opening a new file?

Tags: vim

Today, I realized that I need to convert normal text file into a python list data structure quite often.

Thus I made a vim command-line abbreviation for me.

It looks like this:

```
" wrap all current file datas with python list formats
ca ml %s/^/"/g | %s/$/",/g | 1s/^/[/ | $s/$/]/
```

I've tested the command body part: `%s/^/"/g | %s/$/",/g | 1s/^/[/ | $s/$/]/`.
Which acts as I expected when I paste them into vim command line.

But when I add the above vim config into my `.vimrc`

Every time I opened a new file with vim, it will be executed automatically.

Such as `vim empty_file` will add to the new file the content below:

```
[",]
```

Why this happened?
And how to fix it so that the command body will be executed only when I typed `ml` in the vim command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should replace the `|` characters by `<bar>`:

```
ca ml %s/^/"/g <bar> %s/$/",/g <bar> 1s/^/[/ <bar> $s/$/]/
```

See

```
:h map_bar
```

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: `|` separates commands. So the first `|` will end the definition of the abbreviation and then the substitute commands will be executed. However if you use `<bar>` it will be substituted with `|` only when the abbreviation is expanded.

Comment: @Zen If `|` is used instead of `<bar>` vim will understand that the abbreviation ended and that what followed was another command, as explained in `:h map_bar`.